# xamarin account plugin not visible in visual studio 2010 professional

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I used to work on monodroid in visual studio 2010 prof . But from past two  days I am not able to find xamarin plugin in my visual studio. I dont have any clue as to what happened. 
Is there any solution for this problem?

I uninstalled and reinstalled xamarin but still I could not find. The visual studio application in closed during installation.

Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: you'll be better off contacting Xamarin support, or posting in their Visual Studio forum